# Берется ли в запятые "в частности"?

Tags: пунктуация

Является ли вводным выражение "в частности" в середине слова? Например: "Там было много политиков(,) в частности(,) премьер-министр".

Comment: >выражение "в частности" в середине **слова**  
   
мдя...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется. Т.е. первая запятая нужна, а вторая нет. Сравните. Там был, в частности, премьер-министр. Там было много политиков, в частности премьер-министр".